# Why isn't my template rendering Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So, just a little background ... I need to process data in my controller with data that is coming from the Client side. Thus, knockout.js was suggested.

This particular page has a main page, and then multiple placeholders which all have the same format. The main issue is that only one of these is appearing, and that happens to be the last one. When I inspect element, I see the data present, but not rendered.

here is the code:
First ... the markup for the parent item.

```
@using (Html.BeginFooterScripts())
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Northwestern/js/_libs/knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.2.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Northwestern/js/views/TabPanel/location-card.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var once = true;
        $(function () {
            if (once) {

                initialize();
                once = false;
            }
        });

    </script>
}

<div class="resp-tabs-container tabs-narrow">
    @if (Model.TabSelector.Equals("location-row"))
    {
        <div>
            @*this div needs to be empty. The easyResponsiveTabs plugin adds classes to it and matches it with the <li> in the resp-tab-list above*@

            @*Location List *@

            <div class="@Model.TabSelector">
                <div class="indent">
                    <h3>@Model.Title</h3>
                </div>
                @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("Location-Card")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

The DynamicPlaceholder is where the problem is ... currently there are 9 identical Location-Cards

Here is the markup for the LocationCard.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginFooterScripts())
  {
      <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Northwestern/js/views/TabPanel/location-card.js"></script>


          <script>

              $(function() {
                  geoLocate(function(location) {
                      var latitude = location.coords.latitude;
                      var longitude = location.coords.longitude;
                      displayLocation('@Model.LocationId', latitude, longitude);
                  });

              });


          </script>
      }  





                <div id="detail-container">
                </div>

            <script type="text/html" id="location-detail-template"> 

                                <h2 class="location-title" itemprop="name" data-bind="text: ItemName">@Model.Location.ItemName</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="distance">
                                <i class="material-icons">place</i> <span data-bind="text: Distance.toFixed(1)"> Mi</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="location-phone">
                                <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': clickToCallify(Phone), 'data-track-event': 'Find a Location - Detail', 'data-track-action': 'call icon' }" class="tel" itemprop="telephone">@Model.Location.Phone</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>

            </script> 

        </div>
        <div class="col lg-6 xl-7">

            @(new HtmlString(Model.Body))

        </div>

    </div>
}
```

and here is the Location-card.js

```
var applied = false;
var geoLocateError = function onError(error) {
    alert(error.message);
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentLocation = {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
    };

}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();


$(function () {

});

function initialize() {

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
    geoLocate(function(location) {
        initLocation(location);       
    }, geoLocateError);


}

/**********************************************
* Location Functions
**********************************************/
function initLocation(location) {
    viewModel.currentLocation = {
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude
    };

}


function displayLocation(id, lat, lng) {
    var apiUrl = '/api/northwestern/locations/getlocationbyid/' + id;

    var data = {
        'latitude': lat,
        'longitude': lng
    };

    self.LocationId = id;

    $.getJSON(apiUrl, data, function (response) {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            container = document.createElement('div'),
            viewModel = response;
        fragment.appendChild(container);

        // merge together all the display types into a commma-separated list
        response.TypeListDisplay = $.map(response.Types, function (obj, t) {
            return obj.ItemName;
        }).join(', ');

        ko.renderTemplate(
            "location-detail-template",
            viewModel, {
                afterRender: function () {
                    $('#detail-container').html(container.innerHTML);
                }
            },
            container

        );






    });
}
```

So, I am not certain what to do. I have been working on this now for several days

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty hard to help as there's quite a lot of code. It would be easier if you trimmed the code. Try to cut it down to a *minimal* repro, which ideally also includes boiling it down to a client-side only repro.

Comment: I understand, I modified the amount of code and eliminated the less important pieces.